# Long but easy inequality fails to simplify - where did I go wrong?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, inequalities

Trying to create a simple example I find I need a number of variables.

All my variables are Reals and greater 0. So I use

```
$Assumptions = Element[lab, Reals] && Element[q, Reals] && 
  Element[r, Reals] && Element[s, Reals] && Element[t, Reals] && 
  Element[u, Reals] &&  Element[v, Reals] && 
  lab > 0 && q > 0 && r > 0 && s > 0 && t > 0 &&  u > 0 && v > 0 && q < 1
```

From an equation system I get lengthy solutions having terms like following and I am  interested whether they are smaller 0.

My problem is to weed out the parts that are "obviously" true.  So I actually obtain the following expressions as part of a larger expression.

```
(s (-1 + q - q u)) < 0 // Refine
lab (-1 + q) q u v < 0 // Refine
```

They instantly evaluate to True

But as things get more complex (here just summing the two expressions) - Simplify (or Refine) fail to find the simplification instantly (in the sense that they immediately give up).

```
(s (-1 + q - q u)) + lab (-1 + q) q u v < 0 // Refine
```

I found just if would delete the `lab` it would evaluate nicely.  But since I have many much longer expressions this is not really an option to weed through the sub expressions manually.

All this calculations happen instantaneously and I could definitely live with Mathematica spending some minutes searching for this simplifications.  So I am very open to any suggestions even if they strain my machine a bit.

**Update**

After a few days I also wrote to [community.wolfram.com](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/984576).

A user there suggested to use `Simplify[Equivalent[$Assumptions, 
  Reduce[$Assumptions && (s (-1 + q - q u)) + lab (-1 + q) q u v < 
     0]]]` - which seems to do what I want.

I am not putting it as answer yet as I still am curious why `Simplify` doesn't catch this trivial case.

Comment: Note that `#>0` implies `Reals`

Comment: Thanks that will shorten my code - I just wanted to assure I had all conditions spelled out.

Comment: For those looking at this question, there are definitely some weird things going on here... Looking at the last code line provided in the OP, there's a`q*u*v` in the right term. If you take away `u` the `Refine` doesn't transform the expression, but if you remove the `v` instead it does:
`Refine[(s (-1 + q - q u)) + lab (-1 + q) q v < 0]`
gives `True`.
More generally, you can remove the letter if it doesn't appear in the left term, so
`Refine[(s (-1 + q - q v)) + lab (-1 + q) q v < 0]`
does compute.
Thus *Mathematica* seems to need some sort of factorization to be able to transform it.

Comment: Can use `FindInstance on the reversed inequality to show it cannot be satisfied: `FindInstance[(s (-1 + q - q u)) + lab (-1 + q) q u v >= 0 &&
   lab > 0 && q > 0 && r > 0 && s > 0 && t > 0 && u > 0 && v > 0 && 
  q < 1, {s, q, u, lab, v, r, s, t}]

Out[464]= {}`

Comment: It seems i didn't clearly explain - i'm having a more complex expression - imagine (u-v) multiplied with one of the terms above. And I am after a simplification to (u-v)>0 - if there is any.

Answer (score 4):

To show this, cast it as a quantifier elimination problem and let `Resolve` do what its name implies.

```
Resolve[
 Exists[{s, q, u, lab, v, r, s, t}, 
  lab > 0 && q > 0 && r > 0 && s > 0 && t > 0 && u > 0 && v > 0 && 
   q < 1, (s (-1 + q - q u)) + lab (-1 + q) q u v < 0]]

(* Out[466]= True *)
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know about resolve. I will try it when i get back to the lab.